# Draw rectangle with clear background on top of imageView

Tags: ios, swift, draw, background-color, cgrect

I am trying to draw a rectangle with a random border color with a clear background on top of an `imageView`. I need to loop through a set of co-ordinates and add appropriate rectangles to my image. I can't manage to get the rectangle background colour to be clear. Code below:

`// the draw class`

```
class Draw: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let h = rect.height
        let w = rect.width
        let color:UIColor = Palette.getRandomColour()

        //var drect = CGRect(x: (w * 0.25),y: (h * 0.25),width: (w * 0.5),height: (h * 0.5))
        let drect = CGRect(x: rect.minX ,y: rect.minY , width: w, height: h)
        let bpath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: drect)
        UIColor.clear.setFill()
        color.set()
        bpath.stroke()

        print("it ran")

        NSLog("drawRect has updated the view")                
    }  
}
```

`// and in my viewDidLoad`

```
for bp in sbp {
    if let master = Bodyparts.getID(bp.masterid) {
        let width  = master.x2 - master.x1
        let height = master.y2 - master.y1
        let k = Draw(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: master.x1, y: master.y1), size: CGSize(width: width, height: height)))
        self.imgView.addSubview(k)
    }                        
}
```

Comment: What happens if you don't set the fill color?

Comment: @dasdom the same behaviour with or without the set fill. I am seeing a black rectangle with a random border colour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the background to `clear`.  Here is a playground that you can copy and paste:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class Draw: UIView {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = .clear
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let h = rect.height
    let w = rect.width
    let color:UIColor = .red
    let drect = CGRect(x: rect.minX ,y: rect.minY , width: w, height: h)
    let bpath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: drect)
    UIColor.clear.setFill()
    color.set()
    bpath.stroke()
  }
}
let d = Draw(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
view.backgroundColor = .green
view.addSubview(d)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if mean a transparent center of the rect by clear but you can use the following method.
You would need to set the style of the Paint to stroke, to draw a box instead of a filled rect. Basically you will draw a bounding box if you use the Paint.Style.Stroke option of your Paint.

```
// Give the canvas an image to draw on
val canvas: Canvas = bitmap?.let { Canvas(it) }!!
    
// Test points for rect
val left = 100f
val right = 300f
val top = 100f
val bottom = 500f

// Paint definition for bounding box
var borderPaint: Paint = Paint()
borderPaint.strokeWidth = 10f
borderPaint.color = Color.GREEN
borderPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE

// Draw border
canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom+100, borderPaint)
// Show the bitmap on display
viewBinding.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).